# Is PHP instantiation by class string name an example of reflection?

Tags: php, reflection, terminology

For example, in PHP you can do something like this

```php
$className = 'MyClassName';
$instance = new $className();
```

Would this be considered an example of reflection in php and/or other languages that support similar mechanisms? Or would the meaning of reflection be reserved for something like the below.

```php
$otherInstance = new MyClass();
$className = get_class($otherInstance); #this line would be reflection
$instance = new $className();           #but this wouldn't?
```

In addition, would instantiation through the usage of for example `ReflectionClass::newInstance` be different in these cases and be considered a use of reflection or not?

Comment: Use `ReflectionClass` will not initiate class constructor (`__construct()`). Use `new $className()` will always  called to `__construct()`. `ReflectionClass` can use with abstract class without errors but `new $Class()` will trigger errors if it is abstract class.